# How to get group-level statistics while preserving the original dataframe?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following dataframe

```
one <- c('one',NA,NA,NA,NA,'two',NA,NA)
group1 <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
group2 <- c('C','C','C','D','E','E','F','F')

df = data.frame(one, group1,group2)


> df
   one group1 group2
1  one      A      C
2 <NA>      A      C
3 <NA>      A      C
4 <NA>      A      D
5 <NA>      B      E
6  two      B      E
7 <NA>      B      F
8 <NA>      B      F
```

I want to get the count of non-missing observations of `one` for each combination of `group1` and `group2`.

In Pandas, I would use `groupby(['group1','group2']).transform`, but how can I do that in R? The original dataframe is LARGE.

Expected output is:

```
> df
   one group1 group2 count
1  one      A      C     1
2 <NA>      A      C     1
3 <NA>      A      C     1
4 <NA>      A      D     0
5 <NA>      B      E     1
6  two      B      E     1
7 <NA>      B      F     0
8 <NA>      B      F     0
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please make this example reproducible by posting code to produce your toy data?

Comment: thanks ulfelder but I have the code in Python if that helps you

Comment: No, just post R code here, please. Otherwise anyone trying to help you has to jump through a few hoops first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[,count_B:=sum(!is.na(one)),by=c("group1","group2")]
```

gives:

```
   one group1 group2 count_B
1: one      A      C       1
2:  NA      A      C       1
3:  NA      A      C       1
4:  NA      A      D       0
5:  NA      B      E       1
6: two      B      E       1
7:  NA      B      F       0
8:  NA      B      F       0
```

The idea is to sum the true values (1 once converted to integer) where B is not `NA` while grouping by `group1`and `group2`.

Comment: thanks tensibai! would it be possible to do it with `dplyr` as well?

Comment: If your original df is really large, have a closer look at `data.table`. I'm not a big fan of piping and so not the person to teach you `dplyr` at all. Sorry.

Comment: thanks again for your feedback. I am a novice in R but I have serious experience with Pandas. Would you say that `dplyr` is not meant for large datasets? why not to like piping? I find it very succint

Comment: @Noobie I just mean data.table is faster, due to work by reference. Piping is really good, in shell, but this doesn't scale for multiples operations in R **in my opinion** as it ask the interpreter to move around references between the calls.

Comment: that is interesting. in short, why do you think asking the interpreter to move around references is bad? sorry for my noobiness

Comment: @Noobie And no, piping is not succint, to add a single column that does the trick, try to add 5 related to each others and you'll find why I don't like it at all.

Comment: Great answer. I personally like the list syntax when using `by`, which saves a few quotation marks: `by=.(group1,group2)`

Comment: @noobie If you know pandas, you have some background with python, try thinking about passing a dict to a succession of functions, each time it gets a new memory reference, which will get copied on write if you modify it within the call. That's why I dislike piping :) (and don't worry for "noobiness", there's no harm to ask :p)

Comment: @rosscova I think I got stuck in time where it was not available. And I feel it's something unrelated which has not to be explained by using a vector syntax :p

Answer (score 6):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% mutate(count = sum(!is.na(one)))
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
> Groups: group1, group2 [4]
>
>      one group1 group2 count
>   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>
> 1    one      A      C     1
> 2     NA      A      C     1
> 3     NA      A      C     1
> 4     NA      A      D     0
> 5     NA      B      E     1
> 6    two      B      E     1
> 7     NA      B      F     0
> 8     NA      B      F     0
> ```

Comment: +1 for the tidy solution. I would just add, perhaps it's a good idea to `ungroup` at the end so that subsequent operations are not by group

Answer (score 4):

Let's not forget that a lot of things can be done in `base` R, although sometimes not as efficiently as `data.table` or `dplyr`:

```
df$count<-ave(as.integer(df$one),df[,2:3],FUN=function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
#   one group1 group2 count
#1  one      A      C     1
#2 <NA>      A      C     1
#3 <NA>      A      C     1
#4 <NA>      A      D     0
#5 <NA>      B      E     1
#6  two      B      E     1
#7 <NA>      B      F     0
#8 <NA>      B      F     0
```